# Server Side Compiling of less

Tags: css, asp.net, less

Can we convert less to css from asp.net code behind instead of

1. Generating css on the fly from less in browser
2. Using command line

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Web Essentials Visual Studio extension.

Web essentials can compile less files for you.

[Web essentials less features](http://vswebessentials.com/features/less)

Comment: Actually i want do it Programmatically rather than using extension like web essentials any suggestion ?

Comment: @kishor at company we are using web essentials. You can try this: http://www.dotlesscss.org/ (I am not sure what it's doing, it might help you)

Comment: OK Thanks for feedback, dotlesscss.org compiles less to css on the fly not useful in my scenario